# Equivalent of windows folder icon in font awesome

Tags: icons, font-awesome

In windows an empty folder looks like this:

[image: Empty Folder]

But when it contains some files, it starts reflecting like this:

[image: Non Empty Folder]

I want something similar in Font Awesome.

It has the folder icon viz. https://fontawesome.com/icons/folder?style=solid
which can be used to indicate an empty folder.

However, I could not find anything which indicates a non-empty folder.

Just pitching out here to get some help around the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the "unfilled" folder from regular or light-style for the empty folder and the filled icon to indicate folders with files.
But this would require Pro-Version and I agree that a dedicated icon would be useful. The way to get it into FontAwesome would be via https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome-Pro/issues - although there are a few others already in, so that may require some patience...

And if the initial suggestion does not help as an interim solution, maybe you could go with an [overlay](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering) that uses folder + some other icon specific for the files you're dealing with.